# spark very slow df.coalesce(1).write.parquet

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a very simple PySpark code

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .config('spark.driver.host', '127.0.0.1') \
    .getOrCreate()


data = [('James','','Smith','1991-04-01','M',3000),
  ('Michael','Rose','','2000-05-19','M',4000),
  ('Robert','','Williams','1978-09-05','M',4000),
  ('Maria','Anne','Jones','1967-12-01','F',4000),
  ('Jen','Mary','Brown','1980-02-17','F',-1)
]

columns = ["firstname","middlename","lastname","dob","gender","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = columns)

df.coalesce(1).write.parquet("s3a://sample/tesing.parquet",mode='overwrite')
```

I see the `df.write.parquet` is taking more time. What is the reason. How can I speed it up

Comment: `coalesce(1)` means only 1 executor is writing the dataframe which is the reason why it is slow. You can do a distributed write operation by using all the executors by not coalescing.

Comment: @user238607 This dataframe has 5 rows, would you really expect a performance improvement by distributing that across a cluster (which probably doesn't exist here since it looks like this is running on OP's laptop)?

Comment: he should divide his problem further : write to a local folder and time it. If that doesn't take time, it means the upload to s3 could be problematic.

Comment: I just ran the program locally and it took only 3 seconds to finish the task. Maybe there is some issue with s3 going on.

Comment: Seems like a problem with connect to S3, check your logs for more details.

Comment: how much "more time" is that code taking? what is your benchmark?